# Github API authentication with OAuth (and MFA)

Tags: github, github-api

I am working with a Github Enterprise server. I am using Postman in an attempt to hit the API. No matter what I've tried, I get a "Sign in via LDAP" HTML page returned with a 200 status code. Not exactly what I was hoping for.

Important background:

- MFA is enabled
- OAuth token is a personal access token with all the scopes

I have attempted passing in the token as a URL parameter:

```
https://api.github.mycompany.com/repos/MyOrg/myrepo?access_token=MY_OAUTH_TOKEN
```

I have attempted passing in the token as an Authorization header 3 different ways:

- Authorization: MY_OAUTH_TOKEN
- Authorization: token MY_OAUTH_TOKEN
- Authorization: Bearer MY_OAUTH_TOKEN

From what I glean from the docs, my OAuth token should be sufficient, meaning that I don't need to send any sort of MFA code. Am I wrong? What do I need to do to get real results, rather than the LDAP login page?

Comment: Your URL appears to use an incorrect endpoint. Enterprise uses `/api/v3` instead of the `api.` subdomain.